# Get @JsonProperty values from HashMap

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I have some class using Jackson property to create json report

```
public class Instrument {
    @JsonProperty("one")
    private String myPropOne;
    @JsonProperty("two")
    private String myPropTwo;
    @JsonProperty("three")
    private String myPropThree;
}
```

I am getting data for report from HashMap which has other key-value pairs too.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("one","test1")
myMap.put("two","test2")
myMap.put("three","test3")
myMap.put("four","test4")
myMap.put("five","test5")
```

I only need first one to three values from map other values are used in another class. In output i want to fill in value for Instrument class. Is there a utility to do it cleanly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an instance of the Instrument class to a hash map using the `ObjectMapper.convert` method as follows:

```
public class JacksonConvert {

    static class Instrument {
        @JsonProperty("one")
        private String myPropOne;
        @JsonProperty("two")
        private String myPropTwo;
        @JsonProperty("three")
        private String myPropThree;

        Instrument(
                final String myPropOne,
                final String myPropTwo,
                final String myPropThree) {
            this.myPropOne = myPropOne;
            this.myPropTwo = myPropTwo;
            this.myPropThree = myPropThree;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Instrument instrument = new Instrument("a", "b", "c");
        final Map<String, String> report = objectMapper.convertValue(
                instrument,
                new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
        System.out.println(report);
    }
}
```

Output:

{one=a, two=b, three=c}